# Getting enum values of Pseudo-Enum classes

Tags: enum, powershell, static, properties

By "Pseudo-Enum" classes I mean cases where someone's used a class with public static properties to emulate enum behaviour; e.g. as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15713789/361842).

Per the example below, this is useful for classes such as `[System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon]`, where there is a list of values we're interested in, but no "Get All Values of This Type" method.

I wrote this function for the above type, and it works well for that, but maybe I've missed a trick / there are likely other scenarios that this code could cover which I've not thought of yet.

```
Clear-Host
function Get-EnumValues {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Type]$Type
    )
    process {
        if ($Type) {

            Write-Verbose ("Type: {0}" -f $Type.ToString())
            Write-Verbose ("IsEnum? {0}" -f $Type.IsEnum)

            if ($Type.IsEnum) {
                [System.Enum]::GetNames($Type)
            } else {
                #handle pseudo-enums (i.e. for cases where this trick's been used https://stackoverflow.com/a/15713789/361842)
                $Type.GetFields() | ?{$_.IsStatic -and $_.IsPublic} | select -ExpandProperty Name
            }
        } else {
            Write-Verbose ("TypeName is Null")
            $null
        }
    }
}

$t = [type][System.ConsoleColor]
Get-EnumValues $t -Verbose
$t = [type][System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon]
Get-EnumValues $t -Verbose
```

Output:

> ```
> VERBOSE: Type: System.ConsoleColor
> VERBOSE: IsEnum? True
> Black
> DarkBlue
> DarkGreen
> DarkCyan
> DarkRed
> DarkMagenta
> DarkYellow
> Gray
> DarkGray
> Blue
> Green
> Cyan
> Red
> Magenta
> Yellow
> White
> VERBOSE: Type: System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon
> VERBOSE: IsEnum? False
> Add
> Clear
> Close
> Copy
> Enter
> Exit
> Find
> Format
> Get
> Hide
> Lock
> Move
> New
> Open
> Optimize
> Push
> Pop
> Remove
> Rename
> Reset
> Resize
> Set
> Search
> Show
> Skip
> Step
> Join
> Redo
> Split
> Switch
> Select
> Undo
> Unlock
> Watch
> ```

I'm aware that the shorthand coding style sometimes frowned upon, such as:

```
$Type.GetFields() | ?{$_.IsStatic -and $_.IsPublic} | select -ExpandProperty Name
```

could be written as:

```
$Type.GetFields() | Where-Object{$_.IsStatic -and $_.IsPublic} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

I've taken the view whereby I allow shorthand for the most common, general-purpose cmdlets (i.e. `select` for `select-object`, `%` for `foreach-object`, `?` for `where-object`) as those should be familiar to any powershell developer with any experience; whilst for all others I avoid aliases completely.  My view is that these common aliases are more easily readable, and are unlikely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look for scenarios that this code could cover.

Next 143296.ps1 script, using [`Get-Type` function - Get exported types in the current session](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Type-Get-exported-fee19cf7)

- Exports all types from all namespaces *in the current session* to `$allTypes`, then
- Selects those with non-empty (*pseudo*)enumeration to *auxiliary Hashtable* `$ppp` and `$subTypes`.

**Script** 143296.ps1:

```
Import-Module -Name Reflection -Force
$allTypes = Get-Type -Force -Namespace * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$allTypes.Count
$ppp=@{}              ### auxiliary Hashtable object, could be useful though
$allTypes | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $aux = $_ | Get-EnumValue -AsFlags
        if ( $aux.Count -ne 0 ) { $ppp.add( $_.FullName, $_.BaseType) }
    }
$ppp.Count 
$subTypes = $allTypes | Where-Object { $ppp.ContainsKey($_.FullName)}
$subTypes.Count
$subGrups = $subtypes | Group-Object -Property BaseType
$subGrups.Count
### make public the most frequent items:
$subGrups | Sort-Object -Property Count -Descending | Select-Object -First 15
                                           
<# ### another approach to make public results:
$allBases = $ppp.Keys | %{ "{0,15} {1}" -f ($ppp[$_] | Select -ExpandProperty name), $_ } | sort
$allBases.Count
$subBases = $ppp.Keys | %{ ($ppp[$_] | Select -ExpandProperty name)} | sort -Unique
$subBases.Count
#>
```

**Output**:

> ```
> PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\CR\143296.ps1
> 12413
> 2490
> 2490
> 182
>
> Count Name                      Group                                                          
> ----- ----                      -----                                                          
>  1710 System.Enum               {System.StringSplitOptions, System.StringComparison, System....
>   201 System.Object             {System.String, System.EventArgs, System.BitConverter, Syste...
>    58 System.ValueType          {System.DateTime, System.DateTimeOffset, System.Boolean, Sys...
>    53 System.Attribute          {System.ComponentModel.BindableAttribute, System.ComponentMo...
>    28 System.Windows.Freezable  {System.Windows.Media.Animation.ThicknessKeyFrame, System.Wi...
>    24 System.Windows.Framewo... {System.Windows.Shapes.Shape, System.Windows.Controls.Panel,...
>    22 System.Windows.Control... {Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.OutliningMarginHeaderCon...
>    15 System.Windows.Media.A... {System.Windows.TextDecoration, System.Windows.Media.Animati...
>    11 System.Windows.Control... {System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.B...
>     9 System.Windows.Depende... {System.Windows.Navigation.JournalEntry, System.Windows.Cont...
>     8 System.Globalization.C... {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar, System.Globalizatio...
>     8 System.Windows.Control... {System.Windows.Controls.Canvas, System.Windows.Controls.Vir...
>     7 System.Windows.Media.P... {System.Windows.Media.ArcSegment, System.Windows.Media.Bezie...
>     7 System.Windows.Control... {System.Windows.Controls.Border, System.Windows.Controls.Ink...
>     7 System.Windows.Media.G... {System.Windows.Media.CombinedGeometry, System.Windows.Media...
> ```

The `Get-EnumValue` function is explained using Comment-Based Help (CBH):

```cs
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
function Get-EnumValue { 
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Return names (and values) for an enumeration or enumeration-like object.
 
    .DESCRIPTION
        With -AsFlags or no switch: return Ordered Dictionary of names and values 
                                    for an enumeration (or enumeration-like) object.
        With -NoValues switch: return an array of names for such object.
 
    .PARAMETER Type
        Pass in an actual type, or a string for the type name.

    .PARAMETER NoValues
        If True, then output would be [string[]] array of names;
           otherwise, [OrderedDictionary] type type.
        If True, then -AsFlags parameter is ignored.

    .PARAMETER AsFlags
        If True *and* specified <type> is attributed 'FlagsAttribute' (some [Enum] types)
           then output values would be hexadecimal-like strings (8+ hexadecimal ciphers);
           otherwise, output values would follow <type> type.
        Applies only if -NoValues parameter evaluates to False.

    .INPUTS
        Valid [type], or a string for the type name.
 
    .OUTPUTS
        Always returns [OrderedDictionary] or [system.array] object (see switches).
        Never outputs Null; returns an empty (.Count -eq 0) object instead.
 
    .NOTES
        If -NoValues evaluates to True, then -AsFlags is ignored.
 
    .EXAMPLE
        # Enum, flag enumeration (FlagsAttribute present on object supplied)
        [System.AttributeTargets]|Get-EnumValue -AsFlags -Verbose
    .EXAMPLE
        # Enum, value enumeration (no FlagsAttribute on object supplied)
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.VarEnum]|Get-EnumValue -AsFlags -Verbose
    .EXAMPLE
        # Struct (not Enum)
        [System.Double]|Get-EnumValue -Verbose
    .EXAMPLE
        # Class (not Enum): useful or at least interesting output
        [System.Security.Claims.ClaimValueTypes]|Get-EnumValue -AsFlags | ft -a -Wrap
 
    .REMARKS
        Based on 'Get-EnumValues' function and used in answer to:
        http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143296/getting-enum-values-of-pseudo-enum-classes
        Useful related article: 'Get-Type' - Get exported types in the current session
        https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Type-Get-exported-fee19cf7
    
    .FUNCTIONALITY
        Tested: Windows 8.1/64bit, Powershell 4
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,Position=0)]$Type,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][Switch][bool]$NoValues,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][Switch][bool]$AsFlags
          )
    begin {

        Function EnumNoEnum ([type]$noEnumClass) {
            $enumFlagsHash = [ordered]@{}
            $noEnumClass.GetFields() | 
                Where-Object {$_.IsStatic -and $_.IsPublic} | 
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
                        ForEach-Object {
                            $enumFlagsHash.ADD( $_, $noEnumClass::$_)
                        }
            return $enumFlagsHash
        }

        Function EnumFlags ([type]$enumClass, [bool]$enumFlags) {
            $enumFlagsHash = [ordered]@{}
            [System.Enum]::GetNames($enumClass) | 
                ForEach-Object {
                    if ($enumFlags) {
                        $enumFlagsHash.ADD( $_, "0x{0:x8}" -F $($enumClass::$_.value__))
                    } else {
                        $enumFlagsHash.ADD( $_, $($enumClass::$_.value__))
                    }
                }
            return $enumFlagsHash
        }
    }

    process {
        Try { $Type = [type]$Type} Catch { $Type = $null }
        if ( $Type) {
            Write-Verbose ("Type:   {0}" -f $Type.ToString())
            ### ToDo: find out $enumFlagsAttribute in a more efficient way
            $enumFlagsAttribute = ''
            if ($Type.CustomAttributes | 
                Where-Object {$_.AttributeType.Name -eq 'FlagsAttribute'})
                    { $enumFlagsAttribute = 'FlagsAttribute'}
            Write-Verbose ("IsEnum? {0,-20} {1}" -f 
                $Type.IsEnum.ToString(), $enumFlagsAttribute)

            if ($Type.IsEnum) {
                if (-not $NoValues) {
                    if ( $AsFlags -and $enumFlagsAttribute) {
                        #   flags enumeration
                        $TypeOut = . EnumFlags $Type $AsFlags
                    } else {
                        #   value enumeration
                        $TypeOut = . EnumFlags $Type $False
                    }
                } else {
                    $TypeOut = [System.Enum]::GetNames($Type)
                }
            } else {
                # handle pseudo-enums i.e. for cases where this trick's been used
                #                      http://stackoverflow.com/a/15713789/361842
                if (-not $NoValues) {
                    $TypeOut = . EnumNoEnum $Type
                } else {
                    $TypeOut = $Type.GetFields() | 
                        Where-Object {$_.IsStatic -and $_.IsPublic} | 
                            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
                }
            }
            if ( $TypeOut ) { $TypeOut } else { ,@() }
        } else {
            Write-Verbose ("Null or invalid TypeName")
            if ( $NoValues ) { ,@() } else { [ordered]@{} }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that information about `FlagsAttribute` on a particular `enum` type could matter (added to verbosed output), see [`FlagsAttribute` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

See also the `AsFlags` parameter in the above function: it causes that values of the `FlagsAttribute` enum have a hexadecimal look (fake, however sometimes useful).